# Accessing json returning undefined react js

Tags: json, reactjs, object, react-hooks

I am trying to grab some json data to display in Ui but when I iterate over it using the map method I keep getting undefined.Any help will be really appreciated.Here is a link on code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/late-wood-kx8w2?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
const [items, setItem] = useState(Object.keys(trees));
```

is passing the tree keys to the View function and not the actual data. I believe that you meant to pass the data. Your code passes 'name' and 'children' as {items} that then gets displayed by View.js.

The following code shows you how you can parse the tree and get the names and the values. It's incomplete, but it should give you a start on how to do the traversal.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Start(){
    const trees = {
      name: "root",
      children: [
        {
          name: "child1",
          children: [
            { name: "child1-child1", data: "c1-c1 Hello" },
            { name: "child1-child2", data: "c1-c2 JS" }
          ]
        },
        { name: "child2", data: "c2 World" }
      ]
    };

    const treesCopy = trees;

    function Traverse(tree){
        var treesCopy = tree;
        var str = [];
        for (var prop in treesCopy) {
            console.log(prop);
            if (prop=="children"){
                str = str + "name: "+ prop + ",";
                treesCopy = treesCopy[prop][0];
                // console.log('New tree: ',treesCopy);
                return str + Traverse(treesCopy);
                }
            str = str + "name: "+ prop +" value: " + treesCopy[prop]+",";
            }
        return str;
    };

    const str = Traverse(treesCopy);

    return(
    <>
    {
    str ? str.split(",").map(place => <p> {place} </p>) 
    : ""
    }
    </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @jaesle how can I pass the nested data?

Comment: I actually changed it to Object.values and it renders only the first item root and the rest displayed [Object object]

Comment: I've added some code that should get you started along the right path. It's incomplete, but you can adapt it to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks sir @jaesle I really appreciate everything